# I keep getting errors while trying to read a list of files via "appFolder.GetFilesAsync();"

Tags: c#, uwp, storagefile, windowsiot

I keep getting following Output to Debug.Window.

```
Der Thread 0xd88 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Der Thread 0x6fc hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Der Thread 0xce8 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Der Thread 0x68c hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
```

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace WindowsIOTControlCenter.ImageRotation
{
class ImageRotation
{

    Timer _time;
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> pictures;

    public ImageRotation(Grid targetGrid)
    {
       pictures = scanImagesFolder().Result;
    }

    private async Task<IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>> scanImagesFolder()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFolder appFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("ImageRotation\\BackgroundImages");

            IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> filesInFolder = await appFolder.GetFilesAsync();

            foreach (StorageFile file in filesInFolder)
                Debug.WriteLine(file.Name + ", " + file.DateCreated);
            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
}
```

I used a very basic Example from inet because my original code had the same problem I have now with this example.

I basically want a list of files, located in the specified directory.

Step-by-Step debugging shows no problems assigning the directory to appFolder.

But when it comes to

```
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> filesInFolder = await appFolder.GetFilesAsync();
```

the output mentioned above drops out step-by-step. There's obviously no Exception to catch, otherwise it would continue with catch(Exception ex).

Has anyone a idea what I'm doing wrong or can point out another solution to my problem?

Any hints are apreciated.

P.S.: Sorry for my lousy english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation for the error is "*The thread 0xd88 ended with code 0 (0x0)*". This is not a error, this message is normal for the program to get.

When you do `pictures = scanImagesFolder().Result;` you are likely causing a deadlock on your program by calling `.Result` on a task that uses `await`.

A few things you could do.

1. Use `filesInFolder = await appFolder.GetFilesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`, this makes it so it no longer tries to run the rest of the code on the UI thread so calling `.Result` is ***less likely*** to deadlock. If `GetFilesAsync` does not also use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` you could still deadlock.
2. Move your code out of the constructor and use `await` on your method instead of `.Result`

   ```
   class ImageRotation
   {

       Timer _time;
       IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> pictures;

       public ImageRotation(Grid targetGrid)
       {
       };

       public async Task LoadImages()
       {
          pictures = await scanImagesFolder();
       }
   ```

   This will make the `pictures =` on the same context if you need it. If you don't need that functionality use

   ```
       public async Task LoadImages()
       {
          pictures = await scanImagesFolder().ConfigureAwait(false);
       }
   ```

Please read "[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)", it will teach you the basics like not calling `.Result` and avoiding `async void`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead:
appFolder.GetFilesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)